# python pip: no distributions at all found for an existing package

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the `ScientificPython` package into a newly installed distribution of Python on a Fedora 14 x64 system. Pip finds `ScientificPython` in the repository but does not want to install it

```
[bin]$ sudo ./python2.7 ./pip search ScientificPython
ScientificPython          - Various Python modules for scientific computing

[bin]$ sudo ./python2.7 ./pip install ScientificPython
Downloading/unpacking ScientificPython
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement ScientificPython
No distributions at all found for ScientificPython
Storing complete log in /tmp/tmpDLdmjy
```

Why could this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: So no one knows? My workaround was to download and install ScientificPyton by hand. But it'd be really nice to figure out why pip fails in this case.

Comment: I solved this by setting https_proxy, http_proxy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the [ScientificPython entry on pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ScientificPython) and you will find that it only contains a link to their project page, no downloadable package or egg (which pip would need to install from). That's why pip told you `Could not find any downloads`. You will have to install by hand following their instructions.

Bottom line: if `pip search` lists a given package that doesn't necessarily mean you can `pip install` it (in most cases you fortunately can).

Answer (score 1):

This may due to the unverified files in the installation package . try with the
**--allow-unverified**

> pip install package_name==version --allow-unverified package_name

**example**
pip install django-ajax-filtered-fields==0.5 --allow-unverified django-ajax-filtered-fields

Answer (score -2):

The package name is actually scipy, not ScientificPython

Try:

```
pip install scipy
```

Comment: Thanks for the response reptilicus but `ScientificPython` and `scipy` are not the same. Compare: [ScientificPython](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ScientificPython/2.6) and [scipy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy/0.10.1). `ScientificPython` has facilities for interacting with netCDF files. As far as I know `scipy` does not.

Comment: My apologies! If you need to use NetCDF files, pyTables which should be pip installable provides access to NetCDF /  HDF5 files: http://www.pytables.org/docs/manual-1.4/ch07.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing me toward Tables.NetCDF. I wasn't aware of that and I can definitely make use of it. But, at the risk of being nitpicky, I still would like to understand why pip search sees a package but then pip install does not find any downloads. It's pip I'm trying to understand better in this case.