# PyQt5 in virtual env?

Tags: python, qt

How can I use PyQt5 in a virtual environment? I've tried this:

```
(gui)daniel@yosemite:~$ pip install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyQt5
  No distributions at all found for PyQt5
```

What I want is basically to have the Qt stuff separated from the rest of my system (I don't want to install id system-wide). How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install PyQt5 on a new virtualenv and work on an IDLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042919/how-to-install-pyqt5-on-a-new-virtualenv-and-work-on-an-idle)

Comment: `virtualenv` or `pyenv+virtualenv` If you want further separation (that is Qt libraries, data and binaries isolated to this dev env), use `conda` or even docker/virtualbox/etc